# symbol's function definition is void electric-indent-mode

Tags: debugging, emacs

I am attempting to use Emacs for some (java) development. Unfortunately, anytime I type `else {`, it autoindents the line (significantly too far).

After some googling I have discovered `electric-indent-mode`, however, after hitting `M-x`, `electric-indent-mode` is not available for autocompletion, and when changing my .emacs to include `(electric-indent-mode 0)`, a reload results in `symbol function definition is void`.

How to I disable the indentation? And why am I missing the mode?
Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: `electric-indent-mode` was added in Emacs 24.1